# select matching string from another table oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a database (Oracle) Table A with some strings in one of columns, Now I want to get matching records from Table B against each column value of Table A for example,

Table A

```
Name
-----------
ABC
DEE
GHI
JKL
```

Table B

```
Name
-----------
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
```

Now i want that each string in Table A must be checked against Table B's column and if some string is found almost identical then it should appear against original Value as per below

Table OutPut

```
Name      Matched
--------|----------
ABC     | ABC  
DEE     | DEF
GHI     | GHI
JKL     | JKL
```

I have tried following query

```
with data as(
SELECT Name FROM TABLE_A UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM TABLE_B
)
SELECT Name
FROM
(
SELECT t.*,utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(upper(Name),upper('DEE')) eds
FROM data t
ORDER BY eds DESC
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

but problem is that using this query i can check only one record at a time and that too against a hard coded string. Is there any way to check whole column from Table A one by one against Table B and produce result in output against each string.

Comment: By almost identical, you mean 1 or more characters matching or 2 or more characters matching?

Comment: I have names like unilever Limited in Table A that might be unilever Ltd in Table B, also like it may be "Gauravsa & Company" in Table A and "Gauravsa and Company" in Table B.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not too clever (hint: performance issue, but - see if it helps. Might be OK if there aren't too many rows involved.

You need lines 21 onwards.

I set *similarity* to be greater than 80 - adjust it, if needed (which is very probable, as data you posted is really *sample* data).

```
SQL> WITH ta (name)
  2       AS (SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT 'DEE' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 'GHI' FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 'JKL' FROM DUAL),
  9       tb (name)
 10       AS (SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL
 11           UNION ALL
 12           SELECT 'DEF' FROM DUAL
 13           UNION ALL
 14           SELECT 'GHI' FROM DUAL
 15           UNION ALL
 16           SELECT 'JKL' FROM DUAL
 17           UNION ALL
 18           SELECT 'MNO' FROM DUAL
 19           UNION ALL
 20           SELECT 'PQR' FROM DUAL)
 21  SELECT ta.name,
 22         tb.name,
 23         UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (ta.name, tb.name) sim
 24    FROM ta, tb
 25   WHERE UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (ta.name, tb.name) > 80
 26  ;

NAM NAM        SIM
--- --- ----------
ABC ABC        100
DEE DEF         82
GHI GHI        100
JKL JKL        100

SQL>
```

Comment: With a little change its what i want but you are right performance is a concern using this.